# How to use Master/Detail feature with grouping in AG Grid (React)?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Inspired by this example https://blog.ag-grid.com/column-drill-down-using-master-detail-ag-grid/ I tried to use the Master-Detail feature in the grid that uses grouping (react implementation).

***The expected behavior*** is to have the ability to use Master/Detail where the user be able to click on the number cell of the lowest row in the table (the row that is not a group, with actual data) and display details in Master/Detail component.

But it seems impossible to use Master/Detail with grouping because it overlaps the grouping logic, the example is here https://plnkr.co/edit/hudNcOyseMueFwIR?preview.

***[The AG Grid documentation noted that](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/master-detail-other/#supported-modes)*** `The Master / Detail feature organizes the grid in a way that overlaps with other features. For this reason, Master / Detail does not work with certain grid configurations. These configurations are as follows: Tree Data, Layouts, Range selection`. ***But there is nothing about restrictions with the grouping feature*** (via property rowGroup for colDef).

***So how I can use Master/Detail in the described case?*** if it is possible... The main goal is to implement in React the provided example from the AG Grid site but with a grouping feature.

Comment: This looks fine, I loaded the example provided and was able to expand the group, and then when I expanded the rows, the Detail Grid appeared with no data because it looking for `callRecords` which I'm assuming is part of the default example. What exactly isn't working correctly?

Comment: Hello @GuilhermeLopes! The behavior which I expect: have an icon for Master/Detail only for the data cells on the lowest level of the group, and don't have this for the group level. What we have for now: Master/Detail options also exist on the group level, and as a side-effect when you click on such cell, opens the whole group. Moreover when you click on a cell on the lowest level => triggers all chevron icons in the specific row but I expect to interact with a particular cell.

Comment: Also in my example elements inside `Income` are the data level rows, so they don't have children and they shouldn't have grouping elements. But with master/detail feature this element (I mean chevron icon) appears near `In1`, `In2`, `Liabilities`

Comment: It looks to me like your base example is already too complicated. I wrote this one where the rows are grouped by country, then each Athlete has a detail grid with all medals, hope it helps: https://plnkr.co/edit/qGB8GPTfgHAwygRC